# Passing ASP.NET label id to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I can get the Label value to change when I use the following code

```
  document.getElementById('<%=lblDropdownValue.ClientID %>').innerHTML =     ddl.value;
```

But I would like to pass it as a parameter as shown below, but it does not seem to work.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:DropDownList id="ddlProducts" runat="server" 
           onclick="myfunction(this,'<%=lblDropdownValue.ClientID %> "')">

                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1"> Please Select </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Car"> BMW </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Music"> MP3 </asp:ListItem>

             </asp:DropDownList>

           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:Label Text="" id="lblDropdownValue" runat="server"/>
           </td><td></td>
       </tr>

   </tbody>

</table>
</div>
</form>
<script>
   function myfunction(ddl, lblText)
   {
      document.getElementById("'"+lblText+"'").innerHTML = ddl.value;          
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the code behind:

```
public void Page_Load( ... ) {

    ddlProducts.Attributes["onclick"] = "myfunction(...)";

}
```

and remove the `onclick` from the ASPX.

The reason for this is that you want the `onclick` to be attached at the client side. What you now have is an attribute that is evaluated server side and thus it doesn't make it properly to the client.

Comment: Dziękuję Wiktor Zychla

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind I added

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlProducts.Attributes["onclick"] = "myfunction(this,"+lblDropdownValue.ClientID +");";

        }
```

And Changed the JavaScript to

```
 <script>
        function myfunction(ddl, lblText)
        {            
           lblText.innerHTML
            = ddl.value;          
        }
    </script>
```